How to monitor if a column's maximum allowed range is about to be reached in PostgreSQL?
I would like to monitor columns in PostgreSQL to ensure that they don't exceed the maximum allowed range for their data type. For example, I want to track a PRIMARY KEY with a SMALLINT data type to make sure it doesn't reach the limit of 32,767 records.
I am looking for a way to set up monitoring using postgres_exporter + Prometheus + Grafana. Ideally, I want to have a similar solution to what I have already done with MySQL Exporter. In MySQL, I used the -collect.auto_increment.columns flag with a formula in Grafana:
auto_increment.columns / auto_increment.columns_max * 100
This gives me a percentage view of how close the AUTO_INCREMENT value is to the maximum allowed value.
Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can implement a similar monitoring setup for PostgreSQL? Specifically, how can I extract and monitor the maximum value and the current value of a column (such as a PRIMARY KEY) with Postgres Exporter, so I can use it with Prometheus and Grafana?
I was unsuccessfully trying to :

Checking Postgres Exporter documentation for flags similar to -collect.auto_increment.columns in MySQL Exporter.
Searching for custom Prometheus queries for tracking column values in PostgreSQL.


Using a SMALLINT is very high risk. You only have a few thousand numbers, and the maximum can be reached within a second or on a slow system within seconds. A failed INSERT will still update the underlying sequence. IMHO, there is no point in putting this in a graph; there must be more time to take action when things go wrong. Advice: Use a different datatype like a BIGINT.

Is there some sort of autoincrement on the column e.g serial or Identity?

@FrankHeikens, I used SMALLINT just as an example. In any case, I'm considering all possible scenarios. Of course, there could be other data types with a larger range that would be more appropriate.

@AdrianKlaver, within the scope of the question, there will be auto-incrementing columns. However, I also acknowledge that, theoretically, this type of monitoring could be useful even for non-auto-increment columns

If you're looking for a starting point to build a query that checks the progress of all present sequences, they're listed in information_schema.sequences and pg_sequence, where you can currval(seqrelid::regclass) and compare that to their seqmax, accounting for seqincrement. information_schema.columns holds column_default with a nextval() from them, as well as identity_maximum.

I would think for non auto-increment a better approach would be monitoring on the insert side from whatever application is pushing data into the table where you can leverage tools like Great Expectations or Monte Carlo, although you may be able to leverage those after insert as a reactive tool too. I've not thought about it from that perspective before.

pg_get_serial_sequence() might also be useful, as well as looking up sequence ownership in pg_depend similar to how pg_get_serial_sequence does that.

I agree with Frank. If there's any danger of primary key filling up increase the size of the key now and save yourself a lot of effort and downtime. A table with a smallint primary key has an inconsequential number of rows; increasing its key size should have no impact. I can't think of other possible uses for this monitoring that can't be solved in better ways.

If you don't have a sequence filling the column or an index on it, this monitoring query will become quite expensive. You should narrow the scope e.g. to autoincrementing columns if you want to get a useful answer.
